# C# Windowsform updating dynamic generated combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I think I am overseeing something.

I dynamically generate a few ComboBoxes with this code (I do the same for other controls like TextBox, Label etc)

```
private ComboBox addControlsComboBox(string Id, string TBName, int point_X, int   point_Y, int SizeWidth, DataTable DT)
    {
        ComboBox combobox = new ComboBox();
            combobox.Text = TBName;
            combobox.Location = new Point(point_X, point_Y);
            combobox.Size = new Size(SizeWidth, 20);
            combobox.Name = Id + TBName;
            combobox.DataSource = DT;
            combobox.DisplayMember = "key";
            combobox.ValueMember = "value";
            combobox.Enabled = true;

        return combobox;
    }
```

When I automatically want to set the selected value, for the controls all the values are set correct except for the ComboBox. Not 1 comboBox is updated but all the ComboBoxes.

I use a nested dictionary object to store all the values that i need to match.

See part of the used update Code

```
foreach (Control gb in GroupPanel.Controls)
{
    foreach (Control childc in gb.Controls)
    {
        if (DataCollection[GroupNames].ContainsKey(childc.Name))
        {
            KeyName = childc.Name;
            numberLessKeyName = SL.RemoveDigits(childc.Name);
            TextValue = DataCollection[GroupNames][KeyName];

            switch (NumberLessKeyName)
            {
                case "Name":
                    int IntTextValue = Convert.ToInt32(TextValue);
                    TextValue = IntTextValue.ToString("d2");
                    break;
            }

            switch (childc.GetType().ToString())
            {
                case "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox":
                    childc.Text = TextValue;
                    break;
                case "System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox":
                    // Not Working
                    ComboBox combobox = (ComboBox)childc;
                    combobox.SelectedValue = TextValue;

                    //Also not Working
                    // -->     childc.Text = TextValue;
                    break;
                case "System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox":
                    CheckBox chChildc = (CheckBox)childc;
                    if (TextValue == "Yes")
                    {
                        chChildc.Checked = true;
                    }
                    break;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Can somebody help me please?

[EDIT 1]

Thanks to Karol

I added The Following Lines + interface ICloneable and it worked. Many Thanks.

```
DataTable DT = new DataTable();
DT = DTAttribute;
DataTable DTClone = (DataTable)DT.Clone();
```

For those searching [C# Object Clone Wars][1] [link](http://developerscon.blogspot.nl/2008/06/c-object-clone-wars.html)

[EDIT 2]
A other Idea is to use COPY (works also)

```
DataTable DT = new DataTable();
DT = DTAttribute;
DataTable DTClone = DT.Copy();
```

Comment: What's the condition to select the combobox you wanna update ?

Comment: Why is this tagged `[wpf]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You bind all ComboBox same DataTable.
You must have diffrent instance of DataTable for each ComboBox. You can do this in two ways:
- Once again SELECT data from database.
- Use deep copy to make new instance of DataTable.